# Remove zig-zag part in the intersection curve

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, intersection

I would like to show the intersection between the plane $2x-y-2=0$ and the surface $z=\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}$.

This is what I tried:

```
Show[Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], 
   Sphere[{1.5, 1, Sqrt[4 - 1.5^2 - 1]}, 0.03]}], 
 Graphics3D[Text["2x-y-2=0", {1.7, 1.7, 1.7}]], 
 ContourPlot3D[{z - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2] == 0, 2*x - y - 2 == 0}, {x, 
   0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, 
      f}, (z - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]) - (2*x - y - 2)]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Green}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

As you can see the green curve having the unwanted part. How can I remove this part? If I increase PlotPoints to 60 then I took so long to run and still gave the zig-zag part.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 1

You can use the option [`BoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html) instead of `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` in `ContourPlot3D`:

```
cp1 = ContourPlot3D[{z - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2] == 0, 2*x - y - 2 == 0}, 
  {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> Directive[Green, Thick]}];

Show[Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], Sphere[{1.5, 1, Sqrt[4 - 1.5^2 - 1]}, 0.03]}], 
 Graphics3D[Text["2x-y-2=0", {1.7, 1.7, 1.7}]],
 cp1, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

#### 2

Alternatively, generate the two contour surfaces separately and use the options `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh` in the first `ContourPlot3D`:

```
cp1a = ContourPlot3D[z - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2] == 0, 
   {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {2 # - #2 - 2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]]];

cp1b = ContourPlot3D[2*x - y - 2 == 0, 
   {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]]];

Show[Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], 
   Sphere[{1.5, 1, Sqrt[4 - 1.5^2 - 1]}, 0.03]}], 
 Graphics3D[Text["2x-y-2=0", {1.7, 1.7, 1.7}]], 
 cp1a, 
 cp1b, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

#### 3

Yet another approach is to use `Mesh -> None` in contour plots and generate the green line using `MeshFunctions` in `Plot3D`:

```
Show[Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
  MeshFunctions -> {2 # - #2 - 2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], Sphere[{1.5, 1, Sqrt[4 - 1.5^2 - 1]}, 0.03]}], 
 Graphics3D[Text["2x-y-2=0", {1.7, 1.7, 1.7}]], 
 ContourPlot3D[{z - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2] == 0, 2*x - y - 2 == 0},
  {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]